# Can't create a UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, uitableview, nstablecolumn

I'm trying to creat a UITableViewDataSource, but am getting an error on the following:

```
- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *) aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *) aTableColumn row:(NSInteger) rowIndex 
{
    return nil;
}
```

The error that I'm seeing is:

```
Expected a type (NSTableColumn)
```

So, obviously, NSTableColumn is not defined, but I can't figure out how to get it defined. If I include < NSTableColumn.h >, I get "NSTableColumn.h not found" (note: NSTableColumn.h is from the docs in Apple's "Organizer").

Creating a table view controller can't be this much of a problem, but I can't find the answer. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The NSTableView versus UITableView should have been a clue for me. Somewhere in the searching and tutorials, I got the wrong interface. As such, it isn't surprising I can't find NSTableColumn.